# Inheriting std::stack causes an error with clang but works with gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, stack

**Irrelevant. See update below.**
I've been playing around with std::stack and noticed something strange. Here's the code:

.h file

```
template<typename Tp> using VecOfRef = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Tp>>;

template <typename T>
struct Stack : public std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>> {};

struct Simple {
    std::string txt = "txt";
};
```

.cpp file

```
int main () {

    Simple smpl;

    auto vec = VecOfRef<Simple>{std::ref(smpl)};
    auto stdStack = std::stack<Simple,decltype(vec)>(vec); //works fine
    auto myStack = Stack<Simple>(vec); //error

    //to check if a reference is stored
    stdStack.push(smpl);
    smpl.txt.append("append");
    Simple& r = sStack.top();
    cout << r.txt << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message says:

> 19:
>   No matching conversion for functional-style cast from
>   'std::__1::vector,
>   std::__1::allocator > >' to
>   'Stack'

**UPDATE:**

I have been playing around with this and managed to almost get the code to work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename Tp> using VecOfRef = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Tp>>;

template <typename T>
class Stack : public std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>> {
public:
    using std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>>::stack;
    using std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>>::c;

    T& top() {

        return c.back().get();
    }
};


struct Simple {
    std::string txt = "txt";
    void print() { std::cout << txt << std::endl; }
};


int main() {

    Simple smpl;
    Simple smpl_2;
    Simple smpl_3;

    VecOfRef<Simple> vr {smpl,smpl_2,smpl_3};

//    auto myStack = Stack<Simple> (vr); // error
    auto myStack = Stack<Simple> ({smpl,smpl_2,smpl_3}); // ok
    auto stk = std::stack<Simple,std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Simple>>>(vr); // ok_2

    smpl.txt.append("_append");
    smpl_2.txt.append("_append_2");
    smpl_3.txt.append("_append_3");

    myStack.top().print(); // txt_append_3
    myStack.pop();
    myStack.top().print(); // txt_append_2
    myStack.pop();
    myStack.top().print(); // txt_append

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles under gcc but does not under clang. The error says:

> Error: stack:154:43: No type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

Line in the stack file: [image: error at line]

Comment: Few of the standard classes are designed to be publicly inherited.

Comment: have you tried `auto myStack = Stack<Simple>(stdStack);`

Comment: @Minato The point of having `Stack` is not to use `std::stack` (this is all for educational purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is that you missed a constructor

```
template <typename T>
struct Stack : public std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>> 
{
    Stack(VecOfRef<T>){}
};
```

Comment: I want to inherit constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any constructors to your `Stack` class.

If you want to inherit std:stack's constructors, you must specify that, using:
`using std::stack<T,VecOfRef<T>>::stack;` in your class.

Comment: This rings some bells, but I can't remember why this is necessary.
Also, after putting this line in the `Stack` class I get an error `43: No type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration` in the `<stack>` file on the line `template <class _Alloc>
        _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
        explicit stack(const _Alloc& __a,
                       typename enable_if<uses_allocator<container_type,
                                                         _Alloc>::value>::type* = 0)
            : c(__a) {}`

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee3eeec0fa909ec8) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am having difficulties reproducing the error. It seems to work fine [here](http://rextester.com/SRMH90800) but in Xcode I get an error in the [`stack` header file](http://imgur.com/Kfndker) and it says `No type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration`.